# How can I play multiplayer on NBA 2K14 on pc with my friends?

Tags: nba2k14

I just tried to insert another keyboard in my PC so that I can play with multiple controllers in NBA 2K14, but I am not able to do it. My friends will also be bringing their keyboards. Is there any way we can play on the PC with multiple keyboards?

Comment: Are you sure this game supports local multiplayer?

Answer (score -1):

[Here is a good question](https://superuser.com/questions/135922/why-cant-i-use-two-or-more-keyboards-mice-at-the-same-time-on-one-computer) that was asked on SuperUser about using multiple keyboards on one PC.

It would be much more convenient to plug in multiple gaming controllers into one PC, as those can be mapped much easier to each user.